# get time series in 10 minutes of interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am generating one time-series from using below query.

```
SELECT date_trunc('min', dd):: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone as time_ent 
FROM generate_series ( timestamp '2021-12-09 06:34:37' + ((DATE_PART('min', timestamp '2021-12-09 06:34:37')::integer % 2) || ' minutes') :: INTERVAL 
, '2021-12-10 06:34:37'::timestamp 
, '20 min'::interval) dd
```

and it will give me output like below.

```
2021-12-09 06:34:00.000
2021-12-09 06:54:00.000
2021-12-09 07:14:00.000
2021-12-09 07:34:00.000
```

but I need output like.

```
2021-12-09 06:40:00.000
2021-12-09 07:00:00.000
2021-12-09 07:20:00.000
2021-12-09 07:40:00.000
```

currently, the time series hours depend upon the timestamp that I pass. in above it gives me mins like 34,54,14...but I want the mins like 40,00,20...it should not depend on the time I passed in query. I tried with **timestamp '2021-12-09 06:34:37' + ((DATE_PART('min', timestamp '2021-12-09 06:34:37')::integer % 2) || ' minutes') :: INTERVAL** but not any success.

Comment: Can you describe your exact requirement? If the output shouldn't depend on the input you passed, why it should generate series from `2021-12-09 06:40:00.000`?

Comment: because input is current timestamp but i need time series like 0,20,40 in interval after current timestamp